# A horizontal bundle provides a connection one-form for a principal $G$-bundle

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, lie-groups, connections, principal-bundles

Let's have a principal $G$ bundle $P \xleftarrow{\triangleleft G} P \xrightarrow{\pi} M$. At some point $p \in P$, let's consider the tangent space $T_p P$. We define the vertical tangent space as $V_p P \equiv ker(\pi^*)$ where $\pi^*: T_p P \rightarrow T_{\pi(p)} M$ is the pushforward of the projection $\pi: P \rightarrow M$. The data of a connection now chooses a subspace $H_p P$ such that $H_P \oplus V_p P = T_p P$ and $H_p \cap T_p = \{ 0 \}$. We now wish to show that this data is equivalent to having a Lie algebra valued one form one-form (the connection one-form) $\omega: T_p P \rightarrow \mathfrak g$, where $\mathfrak g$ is the Lie algebra of the Lie group $G$.

I believe the rough sketch of determining $\omega$ from $H_p P$ is as follows:

1. Create an operator $\pi_{vert}: T_p P \rightarrow V_p P$ that projects onto the horizontal subspace.  We can do this by eg. choosing bases for $H_p P, V_p P$ and then keeping only the components of the input vector that are in $V_p P$.
2. We show that $V_p P$ is isomorphic to $\mathfrak g$, thereby letting us reinterpret $\pi_{vert}$ as $\pi_{vert}: T_p P \rightarrow V_p P \simeq \mathfrak g$.

I believe that one can embed $\mathfrak g$ into $V_p P$ by means of defining a map $i_p: \mathfrak  g \rightarrow V_p P$ given by defining a curve $c^a_p: I \rightarrow P$

$$
i_p: \mathfrak g \rightarrow T_p P; i_p(a) = c^a_p \\
c^a_p: I \rightarrow P; c^a_p(t) \equiv \exp(p \triangleleft ta)
$$

One can show $c^a_p$ the curve, interpreted as an element of the tangent space, does live in $T_p P$, and in fact lives in $V_p P$, and all that. (Intuitively, it lives in $V_p P$ because all the points on $c^a_p(t)$ lie in the fiber of $p$. Thus when being projected down onto $M$ by $\pi$, the curve becomes the constant curve $(\pi \circ c^a_p)(t) = \pi(p)$ and thus computes a zero directional derivative.)

What I don't know how to prove is that $i_p: \mathfrak g \rightarrow V_p P$ is **surjective**, and that thus $V_p P \simeq \mathfrak g$. I feel like I don't have any tools that let me relate $V_p P$ and $\mathfrak g$. I tried futzing around with dimensions, but was unable to come up with anything convincing. I'd appreciate all help in showing this.

Comment: The dimension of $V_pP$ is the same as the dimension of each fiber of $P$, which is isomorphic to the group $G$. Therefore, it has the same dimension as $T_eG = \mathfrak{g}$. It follows that any linear embedding $\mathfrak{g} \rightarrow V_pP$ is an isomorphism.

Comment: How do I prove that the dimension of $V_p P$ is the same as the dimension of each fibre of $P$? I understand that $G$ and $T_eG$ have the same dimensions. Could you please elaborate on the relationship? I'd be much obliged!

Comment: $V_p$ is just the tangent space of the fiber.

Comment: I thought about this more. What does it mean to be the "tangent space of the fiber"? I presume we are taking about fibers of $\pi: P \rightarrow M$. Is the idea that because we have a principal $G$ bundle, where the group acts freely and transitively on the fibers, we have that $G \simeq \pi^{-1}(m)$ for $m \in M$? I thought this isomorphism was "as a $G$-set", not "as a group", because the group _acts_ on the fiber; the fiber is not the group itself? I'm clearly confused, and would love some clarification!

Comment: Perhaps more precisely, isn't the fiber $\pi^{-1}(m)$ a $G$-torsor, and not isomorphic to $G$ itself as a group?

Comment: For any $m \in M$ and $p \in \pi^{-1}(m)$, the map $g \rightarrow pg$ is a diffemorphism from $G$ to $\pi^{-1}(m)$.

Answer (score 1):

Since $P$ is a $G$-principal bundle, we have the orbit map of $p \in P$
$$
O_{p}:G \to P \qquad g \mapsto O_{p\cdot g}
$$
given by action of $G$ on the space $P$. For $e \in G$ we obtain
$$
d(O_{p})_{e} : T_{e}G\cong \textbf{g} \to T_{p}P \qquad X \in \mathcal{g} \mapsto p\cdot X = d(O_{p})_{e}(X) 
$$
Now, from orbit map we have that
$$
\pi(p)=\pi(O_{p}(g)) \quad \forall g \in G
$$
Thus, by
$$
(d\pi_{e}(p))X=d\pi_{p}(O_{p}(g))\cdot d(O_{p}(g))_{e}X \quad \forall g \in G
$$
we obtain
$$
0 = d\pi_{p}(p\cdot X), \quad \text{where} \quad p\cdot X \ \text{is a vertical vector field}
$$
Then $V_{p} \cong \textbf{g}$.